Autocomplete on Texstudio not working?
I'm probably missing something super obvious, but I can't get auto complete to work at all. If I start typing any LaTeX command nothing happens and I have to type it all the way through myself.
I just downloaded it on Mac using homebrew.
Since I'd like to write multiple reports with texstudio this is kind of an issue. Any hints?
Edit: in the enormous list in the picture the only checked boxes are: "tex.cwl", "latex-dev.cwl" and "latex-document.cwl"
I'm on version 4.8.1


Can you show Preferences->Completion so we can see which settings you use?

Screenshot added!

Thanks! Looks good. Can you add which version of texstudio you have?

Added now, sorry for the confusion

mmm, looks good as well. I hope some texstudio expert sees your post and has an idea.
